# Зафиксировать отображение в WebView

Tags: android, webview

Есть простой WebView mWeb:

```
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/html"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </WebView>
```

в который я передаю стороку html:

```
mWeb.loadData(myhtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Все работает нормально, но когда при прокрутке нечайно сделаешь свайп влево или прово, текст начинает съезжать. Так вроде и ничего, но тут тоже проблема, текст стает не на прежнее место после свайпа. Как можно зафиксировать отображение содержимого в WebView чтобы не свайпилось по бокам?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно указать действие на свайп:

```
  findViewById(R.id.html).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
           if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) return false;
        }
    });
```